# Downloading and saving streamed video in iOS app (Swift 3.0) using Realm

Tags: swift3, save, realm, ios10, offline-caching

I want to download a video from a url, save it in the app, and be able to play it offline, meaning no internet connection. Is using Realm the best way to do this?

Comment: Which alternatives have you considered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely not. Realm is designed for quickly storing and retrieving collections of basic data types, and this architecture does not work well for large opaque binary blobs. Since Realm uses a memory-mapping mechanism, to access the data on disk, it has specific device-dictated size limits as to how large the data can be that it is able to store.

I recommend you watch the WWDC 2016 video '[What's New in HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/504/)', where system level features for offline caching streaming video were introduced. :)

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Cool! My pleasure! Good luck! :)